# Data is not sent to server using fetch api

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, fetch

I am using fetch api to interact with server. I am trying to send data to server. my front end code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Fetch Testing </title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id = "add"> Add </button>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function(){
      var options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({name: "george", email: "george@g.com"})
      };

      fetch("get.php",options)
      .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
      });
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my server side code (called "get.php") looks like this:

```
<?php
  echo var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

So as you can see I am sending json with properties name and email and their values but it seems that nothing is sent to server because printing the response gives null json and null text.

Comment: What response is in the console?

Comment: What you get in `echo json_encode($_POST);`

Comment: There are many properties in response but both json and text field is empty

Comment: @user2486 exactly same.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API, but from what I have seen it looks like you still need to use a method of the response object to retrieve the data.

Comment: Using the browser developer tools, please inspect the body of the POST request as requested by the browser. Is your data there?

Comment: @JorgeValle how can I do that ?

Comment: @JorgeValle Oh I did it and yes, it's there.

Comment: Good, now if there are no console or network errors in the developer tools, you have ascertained that the front end is working correctly and is sending the right data to the server. That narrows down your debugging to the PHP script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in header, in Content-type I should have written

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded;

instead of

> application/json

Answer (score 0):

Set the responded heading to json get.php:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($_POST);
```